# Rails Display Bootstrap Alerts Using Helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, helper, activeview

I am trying to follow this Gist to display Bootstrap alerts for a crud rails app https://gist.github.com/suryart/7418454. The contents of which have the code:

application_helper.rb:

module ApplicationHelper

```
  def bootstrap_class_for flash_type
    { success: "alert-success", error: "alert-danger", alert: "alert-warning", notice: "alert-info" }[flash_type] || flash_type.to_s
  end

  def flash_messages(opts = {})
    flash.each do |msg_type, message|
      concat(content_tag(:div, message, class: "alert #{bootstrap_class_for(msg_type)} fade in") do 
              concat content_tag(:button, 'x', class: "close", data: { dismiss: 'alert' })
              concat message 
            end)
    end
    nil
  end
```

application.html.erb

```
<body>
    <div class="container">

      <%= flash_messages %>

      <%= yield %>
    </div><!-- /container -->
</body>
```

Problem is I am not seeing any of the messages displayed.

I thought that maybe since the gist is showing to return nil that maybe I need to return the contents of the .each iterator so I did something like this in my helper to return the html:

```
  def flash_messages
    @flash_msg = ""
    flash.each do |msg_type, message|
      @flash_msg = concat(content_tag(:div, message, class: "alert #{bootstrap_class_for(msg_type)} fade in") do
                    concat content_tag(:button, 'x', class: "close", data: { dismiss: 'alert' })
                    concat message
                  end)
      puts "@flash_msg: #{@flash_msg}"
    end
    @flash_msg
  end
```

But when you look at the output of the print statement it is showing me the enter HTML for the page, the end of which is actually the html I need:

```
<div class="alert alert-info fade in"><button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>Signed in successfully.</div>
```

How do I get this to work so that it only returns that last part and not the entire page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use non-output code block: `<% flash_messages %>` (Not `<%=`) along with the original code of your gist.

[concat](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/concat) is responsible for injecting the html markup in the template context and the return value of the helper has no significance.